# Android studio design layout blank

Tags: android

Total novice with Android.
I am trying to create an activity that contains Google maps as a portion of the screen. I am working in Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

I have got the map working as both a stand alone activity and as a fragment, but in both cases the design window is blank (xml code view is normal)
Is there something I am missing?
I have tried everything [HERE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-fix-android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/#:%7E:text=Methods%20to%20Solve%20the%20Problem%201%20Method%201.,is%20not%20working%20properly%20in%20Android%20Studio.%20)

In the example I know there are missing constraints, adding them does not change the outcome.

**Without fragment**
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Sceen1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.086"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.988" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.914"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**With fragment**
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Sceen1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.086"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.988" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.914"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="com.example.a1ststeps.MapsFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="204dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="217dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```